# How to automate accessibility testing with NVDA/jaws screen reader using selenium?

Tags: testing, accessibility

I am working on accessibility for visually impaired individuals for one of the webapplication, presently it's done through manually. I want to automate voice text and write text into some external file.

Can anyone please help me out how it can be done? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about selenium, but the [JAWS Inspect](https://www.paciellogroup.com/products/jaws-inspect/) tool sounds like it does what you want.  You can log the text that is spoken by the JAWS screen reader.

For NVDA, I run with the speech viewer on (Ins+N, Tools, Speech Viewer).  I often copy/paste from this dialog but am not sure how you can automate the logging of that window.  Near the end of [this discussion](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/5010), the user @mahilkr posts a python script to do what you want, but the github repository he points to doesn't exist anymore.  You might be able to track it down.

Answer (score 0):

Let JAWS screen reader read your accessibility while you perform accessibility scenario on web.
create a python script that can read entire text from the screen reader window.
then save it to a path.
then you can validate the data.